# How can I run my Python script as a "drag and drop" icon on the dock? (MacOS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, py2app, dock

I've got a little Python script here for batch renaming files. Really simple.

I'd like to be able to run it simply from the dock, by dragging a folder on to the icon, it will use that folder as the input for the script and run it.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a solution to this?

I've had a little look at Py2App, and will have a play in the coming days, but I'm not quite sure if it's overkill for me.

There is also the AppleScript route, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Py2app can definitely do this, make sure you enable the “argv_emulation” option to convert dragged files to command-line arguments.

That’s assuming you don’t use a GUI library, if you do look into how that library exposed file-open events as the argv_emulation code tends to be incompatible with GUI libraries.